# Where are my azure custom domains

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I had a pay-as-you-go subscription with azure for a while. I ended up canceling it as it got too expensive. However I bought a couple custom domains through azure that I was using. How do I move these domains to my GoDaddy account? I can't seem to find them anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending how you cancelled the subscription you may have lost them, some more information is available here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/custom-dns-web-site-buydomains-web-app/#what-happens-to-the-custom-domain-you-bought

The comments indicate once the subscription is cancelled the domains are sold back and removed from the registry.